# Image gallery with different models and carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have a rails application with 3 models `organization` `campaign` and `vacancy`that all need an image gallery. 
I was thinking of making another model `Gallery` that `has_many` `images` and then use carrierwave to upload multiple images to gallery. How do I associate a gallery model with the 3 different models? A polymorphic association?

Answer (score 0):

you can take gallery model with image field, for upload image with carrier wave and association will be of these type

organization

`has_many :galleries ,:as => :imageable`

campaign 
has_many

`:galleries,:as => :imageable`

vacancy

`has_many :galleries,:as => :imageable`

gallery

`belongs_to :imageable , polymorphic: true`

`imageable_id` and `imageable_type` also will be in gallery model